# How to fix an auto layout constraint shift on an iPad simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, ipad

I have this code for a UITableViewCell subclass,

```
final class SettingsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    // MARK:- Properties
    var switchControl: UISwitch = {
        let switchControl = UISwitch()
        switchControl.isOn = true
        
        return switchControl
    }()
    
    // MARK: - Initializers
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    // MARK:- Methods
    private func commonInit() {
        layer.isOpaque = true
        backgroundColor = .backgroundColor
        configureSwitchControl()
    }
    
    private func configureSwitchControl() {
        switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitchAction), for: .valueChanged)
        addSubview(switchControl)
        switchControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        switchControl.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
        switchControl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    // MARK:- Actions
    @objc private func handleSwitchAction(sender: UISwitch) {

    }
    
}
```

It works fine on an iPhone X simulator,

[image]

But on an iPad Pro(9.7-inch) simulator I have this shift,

[image]

The modalPresentationStyle is not a fullScreen. Is there a way to fix this without changing padding constant?

Comment: Where are you adding these constraints?

Comment: @Frankenstein in a UITableViewCell subclass. Added full code to a question.

Comment: Your constraints seem fine. Although I've added an alternative approach below.

Comment: You cannot add a subview to a cell. Always add a subview only to the cell content view.

Comment: @matt changed it to contentView.addSubview. Same result

Comment: Yes that’s not my point. Bad code is bad code even if it isn’t the cause of the problem you’re asking about.

Comment: @matt Ahhh, sorry. You are right. tableView.frame = view.frame was the problem. Fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What’s off the screen is not the switches but the table view itself. But you did not show that code.